# Multiple custom fields with the same name

Tags: custom-field

Is it possible to have several custom fields with the same name?

For example, I have a custom field called "promotion" for a CPT called "event". Sometimes there are more than one promotion applied to the same event, each for a certain type of participant. So I'd like to have one "promotion" custom field with a value "X, A" and another "promotion" custom field with a value "Y, B".

I tried to create this then retrieve it with `get_post_meta()` and display the result with `print_r()`, but all I get is one of the values only ("X, A").

Here's the code:

```
$event_promotion = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Event Promotion", true); print_r($event_promotion);
```

Perhaps it's just not possible to proceed this way?

Comment: How are you creating your CPT? Can you show code (if using code)?

Comment: @vancoder: hmm why are you asking, does it not occur the same thing with a normal WP post?

Comment: simply to ascertain how you are setting up your custom fields. If you are just using 'off the shelf' custom fields, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can have multiple custom field values using the same key. Using `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'your-key' )` _should_ return an array containing every value using that key. Can you post the actual `get_post_meta()` code you're using?

Comment: Here's the code : $event_promotion = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Event Promotion", true); print_r($event_promotion);

Comment: The third parameter needs to be `false` if you want an array of all values returned. I've added an actual answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have multiple fields with the same key.

When using `get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single)`, make sure you set the `$single` parameter to `false` (or just leave it off since it defaults to `false`).

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Event Promotion', false )
```

or

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Event Promotion' )
```

This will return an array containing every value of the key (what you're expecting). If you set `$single` to `true` it will return the first value of the specified key as a string (what you're currently getting).

References:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

this is how PHP handles names. try naming your fields promotion[] to let PHP know it's an array of elements.