# how to get post meta where value is an array of key value pairs

Tags: meta-query

I am trying to get the post meta with meta query where value is an array of key value pairs.

```
 $user_id = '123';

  $arr = array();

  $arr['a'] => "somevalaaa" ;
  $arr['user_id'] => $user_id ;
  $arr['c'] => "somevalyyy" ;
```

Adding post meta

```
  add_post_meta($review_post_id, 'key_of_post_meta', $arr );
```

Getting post meta (having user id same as $user_id) with meta query, where I am wrong ?

```
  $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'as_reviews',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
          'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                'key' => 'key_of_post_meta',
                'value' => array('user_id'=>$user_id),
                'compare' => 'IN',
               ),
            ),
       );



  $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Why not create a for loop where every run changes the `key` and `value` in the query?

Comment: that is not the case

Comment: Please see previous questions and answers on the matter: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16709/meta-query-with-meta-values-as-serialize-arrays Short version: This is a poor way to store data you intend to query, and you should store it differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [meta_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) cannot be used to search value which are stored as serialized arrays.  You can use it to search multiple values (meta-fields can have [several values using the same key](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94183/multiple-custom-fields-with-the-same-name)).

You need a different approach to solve your problem, this is what I suggest,

store your meta field with the user id as part of the key name,

```
add_post_meta($review_post_id, 'key_of_post_meta_'.$user_id, $arr );
```

next, retrieve your posts with,

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'as_reviews',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'meta_key' => 'key_of_post_meta_'.$user_id
    );
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: hmmmm, I like your idea

Comment: let me try with that

Comment: @NickTaylor did u manage to get it to work?

Comment: oh yes that works